# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type found for dependency

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, authentication

I am getting the following error when I try to run the project in Eclipse. I tried different solutions from similar questions but not able to figure out the exact problem.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [4]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authService' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.demo.dao.UserDAO com.demo.service.impl.AuthServiceImpl.userDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.demo.dao.UserDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)

My `security.xml` is:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>

<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>

<http access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/forgotPasswordJson" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resetPassword" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/loginfailed" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/setTimezoneOffset" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/info/termsOfService" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
    <form-login login-page='/login' authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationHandler" />
    <logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" logout-success-url="/login" logout-url="/logout" invalidate-session="true"/>
    <session-management session-authentication-error-url="/loginfailed" session-fixation-protection="newSession">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="100" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </session-management>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="authService" />
</authentication-manager>
<beans:bean id="authService" class="com.demo.service.impl.AuthServiceImpl" />
<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationHandler" class="com.demo.security.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
```

My `DaoImpl` is:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public User findUser(String userName, boolean allData)
{
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) logger.debug("Finding user by user name \"" + userName + "\"");

    List<User> list = entityManager.createQuery("from User u where upper(u.userName) = :name")
            .setParameter("name", userName.toUpperCase()).getResultList();

    if (list.size() != 1) return null;
    User u = list.get(0);

    if (u != null && allData)
    {
        Hibernate.initialize(u.getClients());
        Hibernate.initialize(u.getRoles());
    }

    return u;
}
```

My `AuthServiceImpl` is:

```
@Service
public class AuthServiceImpl implements AuthSerice, AuthenticationProvider {

@Autowired
UserDAO userDao;
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
  throws AuthenticationException {
    System.out.println("Entered Java auth");
    String name = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

    User details = userDao.findUser(name, true);
    Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
    SimpleGrantedAuthority userAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(
            "ROLE_USER");
    SimpleGrantedAuthority adminAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(
            "ROLE_ADMIN");
    authorities.add(userAuthority);
    authorities.add(adminAuthority);

    if (password.equals(details.getPassword())) {
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, authorities);
    } else {
        //throw new AuthenticationException("Unable to auth against third party systems");
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
}
```

My web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" 
     version="2.5"
     metadata-complete="true">

<display-name>MainWebsite</display-name>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>120</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
                 /WEB-INF/spring/security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Filters -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>/spring</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/spring-form.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

Here, I am trying to authenticate user from a Java class rather than using a query in XML to authenticate.

My `context:component-scan` is in `servlet-context.xml`. If I add `<beans:bean class="com.demo.dao.impl.UserDAOImpl"/>` in `security.xml`, the error is changing. I think the error might be because of the xml loading priorities.

**P.S.:** The bad fix would be moving the `servlet-context.xml` to `WEB-INF` folder, renaming it accordingly and then adding/declaring it in `web.xml` along with other XML files..

Comment: Show us `UserDaoImpl` class signature with package and annotations. Does it have `@Repository` or `@Component` annotation?

Comment: @TomášPiňos Thanks for the reply. It has `@Repository` annotation

Comment: @TomášPiňos I edited the question.. please look into `web.xml` also

Comment: @TomášPiňos  Look at the P.S. I added. Probably that will help to analyze things better.

Answer (score 0):

There's classpath scanning configured for `com.vigillo.mainwebsiteroot` package, but it seems your classes are located in `com.demo` package.

So it seems your intention was to declare `com.demo` classes explicitely.

There're authService and customAuthenticationHandler beans defined, but there's no userDao been in the context. That's probably the issue.

Define it and see what happens.

```
<beans:bean id="userDao" class="com.demo...UseDaoImpl"/>
```

Comment: Sorry the vigillo part was a mistake.... I took the code from else where and tried to change things...

Comment: When I do that, It gives NoSuchBeanDefinition for EntityManager (which is used in DaoImpl). When I move the entity manager related stuff to `security.xml` , then it needs some other related thing. I feel the `servlet-context.xml` is not loaded before `security.xml` or something of that sort